# How to put file from local computer to HDFS

Tags: hdfs, webhdfs

Is there any way to push files from local compute to HDFS.

I have tried to send GET request to port 50070 but It always shows
Authentication required.

Please help me ! I am quite new to HDFS

Comment: hdfs dfs -copyfromlocal localname hdfsfilename

Answer (score 0):

To create new folder

> hadoop fs -mkdir your-folder-path-on-HDFS

Example

> hadoop fs -mkdir /folder1 /folder2
>
> hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://:/folder1

Uploading your file

> bin/hdfs dfs –put ~/#youruploadfolderpath# /#yourhadoopfoldername#